# Increase Google Sheets API Time of Life

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to increase the TOL for a user who is using Google Sheets API calls.

There is a lot of documentation I see regarding this, but I seem to be missing where you actually make the change.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that with `TOL` you mean the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#:%7E:text=This%20version%20of%20the%20Google,is%20no%20daily%20usage%20limit.) related to the API requests

- To increase the quota limit you need to follow these steps:

  - Link a [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account) to your [Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)
  - Search and enable the Google Sheets API in the [library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?) of the API Console
  - Click on `Manage` > `Quotas` to see your usage.
  - Go to [Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=sheets.googleapis.com) and filter by Google Sheets API, there is a link on the last window.
  - Select all the quotas that you want to modify by clicking on its `Limit name` and then on `Global`
  - Click on `Edit quotas` and write a description of your request including the intent of the quota usage, future growth plans, region or zone spread, and any additional requirements or dependencies.